# Extract part of object using python script

Tags: python

I have a model of the inside of a mouth and I need to extract the teeth from it and remove the gums. How can I go about this?

I've tried search for manipulating meshes, layers but don't know where to start.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since it was a single mesh, you may want to split the parts by cutting. Try **Knife Cut** tool, which can be found in Toolshelf sidebar when in Edit Mode.

Comment: That would be me manually extracting them. I want to do this via a python script.

Comment: I guess the q is How to define what is a tooth and what is a gum. What rule would you propose to the script? First idea would be to look for predominantly concave areas (this is available, mesh/ bmesh stuff). Predominant, so that you do not find all little gaps or so, just major "inset" lines. Tough one ...

Comment: yes that's what I had in mind. Wanted to know what other options I have so posted here

Comment: could you post a blend with part of that model? I don't wanna try things on a model that is different, it will be misleading (and, ok, I don't wanna sculpt something like this :) )

Comment: here you go https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By_H6jYzgbZfT2NFdDRaWHMyMTQ/view?usp=sharing
For now I have thought of scanning the faces (via a breadth first search maybe?) and checking for concave and convex curves which can be the part where one tooth ends and another starts and where the tooth end and the gums start. Don't know if it will work I have yet to try this though

Comment: @o.g. Let me know if you have anything

Comment: I'm looking at it, but works very hard and even crashes B (very big blends..)  I'll post what I find useful...

Comment: great thanks! i'll update if i have anything too